# Find out the admin(s) for a git repo

Tags: git, github

I am a contributor for a git repo in github for a company.

I want to find out who among the contributors are the admins.

How do I find out who is the admin besides going around and asking everyone in the company?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to figure that out on Github itself unfortunately.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you have push access to this repository, you can use Github API to find [collaborators](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/)

You will need an [access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens), the endpoint `https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/collaborators` gives you a list of all collaborators with the list of permission type for each of them :

```json
"permissions": {
    "admin": true,
    "push": true,
    "pull": true
  }
```

You can use [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (to parse JSON response) like this :

```bash
curl https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/collaborators \
     -H "Authorization: Token ACCESS_TOKEN" | \
     jq '[ .[] | select(.permissions.admin == true) | .login ]'
```

Comment: Def not what I was expecting but does the job. You rule @Bertrand Martel

Comment: What scope is needed for the access token? I do not see anything specified at the API endpoint doc: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#list-collaborators

Comment: @einnocent the narrower scope is `public_repo` scope if the repo is public see [the list of scopes](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes). If the repo is private the `repo` scope is necessary

Comment: Adding `repo` scope to my access token for use against a private repo worked.

Comment: I ran the exact url you put up here and I got {"message: "Not Found", "documentation_url": "URL"} exeception in JSON format

Comment: is there a reason why this isn't a simple 'users' tab in the repo accessible to regular contributors?

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the v4 (GraphQL) [API](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) for this:

```
query { 
  repository (owner:"ORG",name:"REPO") {
    collaborators (first:100) {
      totalCount
      edges {      
        permission
        node {
          login
          name  
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and look for results that have `"permission": "ADMIN"`

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Must have push access to view repository collaborators." 
Any idea how to fix that or am I simply not allowed to view the collaborators for a public repo that I'm not able to push to?

Comment: @majorBummer it seems there is a way around this [here](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/issues/1070#issuecomment-177992285)

Comment: @jnnnnn that workaround only seems to tell you information about the current user. I can find out if I am admin; this question is finding out who is admin when I am not admin.

Comment: Do you know how to filter those with ADMIN permission? The list is too long in my case and it can only return 100 results

Comment: @ChenNi I tried to filter but couldn't find a way. Maybe one has been added since then; otherwise you will need to use the graphql paging -- I think `endCursor` is the bookmark

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer python code:

```
def headers(token: str):
    return {"Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",  "Authorization": "Bearer " + token}

def collaborators(api_base: str, token: str, org: str, repo: str):
    users = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo}/collaborators', headers=headers(token)).json()
    return [x['login'] for x in users if x['permissions']['admin']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out via github's web api.
Replace docker below with the name of the organization.

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/docker/members?role=admin
```