# How to check if we are the owners of the repository?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm using Github API to fetch data from my repository like below:

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world
```

documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository

to run this query, in header, I'm also using my access token,

and I have one question, is there any way to check from github api response, that I'm the owner of the repository? I want to create a simple statement that check if responsed repository from github api is my or not(different public repo),

thanks for any help!

Comment: This is not a coding question and not on topic, I suggest you ask on another StackExchange site like [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: What do you mean by "the owner"?  Literally, GitHub thinks of you as the owner of any repo beneath your account; if you are user `foo` then you are the repo of any repo `foo/*`.

Comment: maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538330/find-out-who-is-the-admins-for-a-git-repo